# How to check to see if a windows driver has a EV certificate or not?

Tags: windows, certificate, driver

So in windows you can go to digital signature tab to check the file's certificate, but how can i check if the certificate is a EV certificate or not? does it show it somewhere in the details of the certificate?

More clear question : lets say you have a signed driver in windows, how can you check if it has a EV certificate or not?

Answer (score 1):

> EV certificates are standard X.509 digital certificates. The primary way to identify an EV certificate is by referencing the Certificate Policies extension field. Each issuer uses a different object identifier (OID) in this field to identify their EV certificates, and each OID is documented in the issuer's Certification Practice Statement. As with root certificate authorities in general, browsers may not recognize all issuers.
> EV HTTPS certificates contain a subject with X.509 OIDs for jurisdictionOfIncorporationCountryName (OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3),[11] jurisdictionOfIncorporationStateOrProvinceName (OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2) (optional),[12]jurisdictionLocalityName (OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.1) (optional),[13] businessCategory (OID: 2.5.4.15) and serialNumber (OID: 2.5.4.5), with the serialNumber pointing to the ID at the relevant secretary of state (US) or government business registrar (outside US), as well as a CA-specific policy identifier so that EV-aware software, such as a web browser, can recognize them. This identifier is what defines EV certificate and is the difference with OV certificate.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)

There is no way to identify the EV certificate technically.
The browser vendors maintain lists of Policy OIDs. Here is the one of Google Chrome: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/cert/ev_root_ca_metadata.cc

As an example:

```
    // AddTrust External CA Root
    // https://addtrustexternalcaroot-ev.comodoca.com
    {
        {{0x68, 0x7f, 0xa4, 0x51, 0x38, 0x22, 0x78, 0xff, 0xf0, 0xc8, 0xb1,
          0x1f, 0x8d, 0x43, 0xd5, 0x76, 0x67, 0x1c, 0x6e, 0xb2, 0xbc, 0xea,
          0xb4, 0x13, 0xfb, 0x83, 0xd9, 0x65, 0xd0, 0x6d, 0x2f, 0xf2}},
        {
            "1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.1.5.1",
            // This is the Network Solutions EV OID. However, this root
            // cross-certifies NetSol and so we need it here too.
            "1.3.6.1.4.1.782.1.2.1.8.1",
        },
    },
```

You will find the OID "1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.1.5.1" or "1.3.6.1.4.1.782.1.2.1.8.1" in every EV certificate issued by "AddTrust External CA Root". This is how they are identified.

Comment: "There is no way to identify the EV certificate technically" then how does windows detect if a certificate is EV or not to let the driver load in secure boot, since only drivers with EV certificate can load with secure boot on?

Comment: As Google Chrome does, by using a hard coded (allow) list.

Comment: How is that possible when there are thousands of EV certs and new one get issued everyday? so you are saying they "hardcode" the EV certificates list in kernel or something?!!

Comment: The root CAs (the end of the trust chain) are in the list, not the certificates itself.

Answer (score 1):

EV certificate depend on intermediate certificate.

windows load if the driver signature cross-signed with "Microsoft code verification root"

use `signtool verify /v /kp Filename.sys` and check "Cross Certificate Chain" part, you should see "Microsoft Code Verification Root"